# Routing role in asp.net core isn't working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using mvc, in the startup.cs there is a part that looks like this:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Changing controller to Account and action to login gives me an error 404 not found after restarting the website. Am i missing something?

Comment: And you have an AccountController with a Login action?

Comment: If you selected defaults and selected individual accounts at the time of creation then you should have all the above.  But because the route for Login doesn't take an `Id` but a `string returnUrl = null` of course it 404'd because the default route was not met.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information. We need to see some controllers and actions

Answer (score 0):

I would first verify in Startup.cs that your app.UseMvc(...) is at the end of your Configure method. Then verify your controller inherits from Controller, and you don't have a [Route] attribute on it.

If those dont solve it, take a look at the sample music store application [Startup.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/5086579c4259ba6e8a7ff9d7edd808d62f2396e4/samples/MusicStore/Startup.cs#L197) file and [sample controller](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/5086579c4259ba6e8a7ff9d7edd808d62f2396e4/samples/MusicStore/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L17) to see if you see anything missing. Unfortunately without more information its a guess as what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

Look for attribute routing in your AccountController, if it exists it will crash with your startup.cs routing options, so just comment it out and it should work.